# Trying to filter a data frame based on consecutive words in description variables (R)

Tags: r

Asking around to troubleshoot solutions for a project I'm doing in R. I have a data frame with every pitch from the previous season in professional baseball, and I'm trying to assign plays to the fielder that got to the ball first. To do this, I'm trying to manipulate description variables (des), which look something like this.

"Gary Sanchez grounds out, third baseman Eugenio Suarez to first baseman Ty France."

In this instance, my goal would be to assign this play to Eugenio Suarez, as he was the one the ball was hit to. To give this a test run, I decided to use grepl (I've used it to separate certain plays in the past). To make sure it wouldn't include plays the third baseman was involved in but not the original fielder, I tried something like this.

`DF %>% filter(grepl(", third baseman", des) == T)`

Commas and "to" are integral in determining the original fielder from these description variables, but grepl simply filtered for every description that had a comma and which a third baseman was involved in.

Is there some function or way I could filter for consecutive characters so that that previous filter would query plays like the original? Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Are you searching something like `DF %>% filter(grepl(", third baseman .* to ", des) == T)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but it seems like you need a look around in the regexp.

If you want to filter for all the plays with third baseman Eugenio Suarez:

```
grepl("(?<=, third baseman )Eugenio Suarez", desc, perl = TRUE)
```

This finds all the descriptions where the name "Eugenio Suarez" is preceded by ", third baseman ".

If you want to just extract the name, you can use a function like `stringr::str_extract`:

```
stringr::str_extract(desc, "(?<=, third baseman )(Eugenio Suarez)")
```

You can generalize this if the person is always two names an followed by " to" by using the followed by look around:

```
stringr::str_extract(desc, "[[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+(?= to)")
```